# Combine TOPCOUNT, and BOTTOMCOUNT resultset in MDX

Tags: mdx, olap, bids

I am new to MDX, and have a simple requirement which would be easy to do with SQL, but I would like to accomplish this with MDX.

I would like to combine the result, of 2 queries, so when quering the cube, I only send over 1 query.

```
 
select topcount( [Fact].[Year].children, 1,[Measures].[MoneyIn]) on columns
from [Cube]
```

and also this MDX query, to get the least money in, for a period of years.

```
 
select bottomcount( [Fact].[Year].children, 1,[Measures].[MoneyIn]) on columns
from [Cube]
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this with MDX? Ideally I would have something :

```
MaxValue MinValue
10k      -10k
```

Thanks! All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your query a few different ways.  This puts the counts in one column:

```
SELECT [Measures].[MoneyIn] ON COLUMNS,
{TOPCOUNT([Fact].[Year].children,1, [Measures].[MoneyIn]),
BOTTOMCOUNT([Fact].[Year].children,1, [Measures].[MoneyIn])} ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

This is closer to your output but without the named columns

```
SELECT [Measures].[MoneyIn] *
       {TOPCOUNT([Fact].[Year].children,1, [Measures].[MoneyIn]),
        BOTTOMCOUNT([Fact].[Year].children,1, [Measures].[MoneyIn])
       } ON COLUMNS
FROM [Cube]
```